# Loop cut going through Ngons?

Tags: modeling

[image]

[image]

Hello! I'm fairly new to blender, and I am having an issue with the loopcut tool. It seems to cut through ngons. In other modeling tools I've used, the loop usually stop at ngons. I guess this could be a feature in some circumstances, but in other circumstance a partial loopcut would be more convenient, especially if you try to do something a bit more specific in the ngons area (for example, cutting out a shape and then connecting it back to some partial loops via the knife tool).

Is there any way to make the loopcut tool not cut through ngons? It's weird because when I was researching this problem, the only posts I found were from people have the exact opposite problem of not being able to cut through ngons. Perhaps it was a recent change?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You just show the example, then loop cut starts and ends at the same N-gon. In this case, Blender connect the start and the end. But if you try to add more N-gons, you will see the difference

[image]